# How to pull android application code after installing application from android market

Tags: android, command-prompt, pull

is there any possibility that we can pull the android application code after installing the application from android market.

How can i pull that code??

please help me out.

Comment: no option you'll have to build new apk and install

Comment: Your source code won't have changed after you install from market... unless, of course, you want to get to someone else's source-code. You won't get help with attempting software piracy here.

Comment: what you are asking is called "Reverse Engineering" , just google it, you may find some tips.

Comment: Hi @Husker we can do reverse engineering when we have apk file with us, but in my case the application was installed from android market.can e get .apk file of installed app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Before I make the suggestions, me being aware of how to do it, does not mean I condone such a task.*

There are a few tools you can use to get what you need:

1. The [APK Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1310151) Utility
2. The [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) Utility

You will need to naturally have to have a rooted device for pulling APK's off the system partition.

If you need to the see the XML's (resource files), the *APK Manager* is the one for you. And if you need to see the JAVA code, you will need to follow the *dex2jar* utility.

Note: dex2jar will not show the **actual** code that you would see in your project under eclipse. You will need to join a lot of dots along with a ton of assumptions.

*And this is where I end the post and draw the line. Not a big fan of seeing how other developer build their applications. I would rather make a miserable application than blatantly copying or even referring to someone else's hard work.*